# What is non-sub modelling?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

What is non-sub modeling? For what purpose and where is it used?I have some knowledge on the subject, but I'm asking because I don't fully understand and I'm not sure. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: I don't know if that's a standardized term, but I assume it means modelling without the use of a subdivision surface modifier.  Subdivision surface naturally curves and smooths edges, but at the cost of extra geometry. I assume "non-sub" would be trying to achieve the same curved, smooth effect, but without the modifier or the extra geometry that comes with it (low poly modelling, essentially).

Comment: What's the context in which you heard it used?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I answered before I saw your comment.  If you'd like to turn your comment into an answer, I'll remove mine.

Comment: @Marty Fouts - Its all good - all I planned to do was leave the comment anyways. Go for it.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112221/when-and-when-not-to-use-subdivsion-surfaces/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99412/what-exactly-is-hard-surface-modelling

Comment: For example, in some videos I watched, neither boolean nor subd were used in accessories such as environmental design. This made me suspicious. This leaves us with the choice. We can model both methods without using subd and boolean. I can model using both methods, but this dilemma confuses me. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

*non-sub*, usually *non-sub D*, is a term used to describe a range of Blender modeling techniques that do not use the [subdivision surface modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html).

Modeling techniques based entirely on sculpting fall into this category, as do techniques that use non-destructive boolean workflow for creating *Hard Surface* models.

A common difference between hard surface techniques that use subd and those that don't:  subd techniques use [*loop cut*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html) and similar tools to control the sharpness of corners, where non-subd techniques tend to use *bevels* for the same purpose.

There are several arguments for avoiding subd, the most common being that subd creates a great deal of unnecessary geometry.  That makes non-sub popular with low poly count modelers, especially those creating assets that are meant for export to game engines.